# SpringDataJPA with dual data source is not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a spring boot application with 2 datasources I have also created a configs for two data sources.

application.yml:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
  datasource:
    one:
      url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test-one
      username: postgres
      password: root
      driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    two:
      url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test-two
      username: postgres
      password: root
      driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
```

OneConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = OneConfig.ONE_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME,
        transactionManagerRef = OneConfig.ONE_TRANSACTION_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME,
        basePackages = { OneConfig.ONE_REPOSITORY_PACKAGE }
        //basePackageClasses = { UserPostgresRepositoryOne.class }
)
public class OneConfig {

    private static final String ONE_DATASOURCE_PROPERTIES_BEAN_NAME = "oneDatasourceProperties";
    private static final String ONE_DATASOURCE_BEAN_NAME = "oneDataSource";
    private static final String ONE_DATASOURCE_PREFIX = "spring.datasource.one";
    private static final String ONE_DATASOURCE_CONFIGURATION_PREFIX = "spring.datasource.one.configuration";
    private static final String[] ONE_ENTITY_PACKAGES = { "com.one.two_sql_and_one_nosql.entities.postgres_one" };
    private static final Class<?>[] ONE_ENTITY_CLASSES = { UserPostgresModelOne.class };
    static final String ONE_REPOSITORY_PACKAGE = "com.one.two_sql_and_one_nosql.repositories.postgres_one";
    static final String ONE_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME = "oneEntityManagerFactory";
    static final String ONE_TRANSACTION_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME = "oneTransactionManager";

    @Primary
    @Bean(ONE_DATASOURCE_PROPERTIES_BEAN_NAME)
    @ConfigurationProperties(ONE_DATASOURCE_PREFIX)
    public DataSourceProperties oneDatasourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = ONE_DATASOURCE_BEAN_NAME)
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = ONE_DATASOURCE_CONFIGURATION_PREFIX)
    public DataSource oneDataSource(
            @Qualifier(ONE_DATASOURCE_PROPERTIES_BEAN_NAME) DataSourceProperties oneDataSourceProperties) {
        return oneDataSourceProperties
                .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = ONE_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME)
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean oneLocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier(ONE_DATASOURCE_BEAN_NAME) DataSource oneDataSource
    ) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(oneDataSource)
                .packages(ONE_ENTITY_PACKAGES)
                //.packages(ONE_ENTITY_CLASSES)
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = ONE_TRANSACTION_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME)
    public PlatformTransactionManager onePlatformTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier(ONE_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME)
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean oneEntityManagerFactory
    ) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(Objects.requireNonNull(oneEntityManagerFactory.getObject()));
    }
}
```

TwoConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = TwoConfig.TWO_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME,
        transactionManagerRef = TwoConfig.TWO_TRANSACTION_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME,
        basePackages = { TwoConfig.TWO_REPOSITORY_PACKAGE }
        //basePackageClasses = { UserPostgresRepositoryTwo.class }
)
public class TwoConfig {

    private static final String TWO_DATASOURCE_PROPERTIES_BEAN_NAME = "twoDatasourceProperties";
    private static final String TWO_DATASOURCE_BEAN_NAME = "twoDataSource";
    private static final String TWO_DATASOURCE_PREFIX = "spring.datasource.two";
    private static final String TWO_DATASOURCE_CONFIGURATION_PREFIX = "spring.datasource.two.configuration";
    private static final String[] TWO_ENTITY_PACKAGES = { "com.two.two_sql_and_one_nosql.entities.postgres_two" };
    private static final Class<?>[] TWO_ENTITY_CLASSES = { UserPostgresModelTwo.class };
    static final String TWO_REPOSITORY_PACKAGE = "com.two.two_sql_and_one_nosql.repositories.postgres_two";
    static final String TWO_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME = "twoEntityManagerFactory";
    static final String TWO_TRANSACTION_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME = "twoTransactionManager";

    @Bean(name = TWO_DATASOURCE_PROPERTIES_BEAN_NAME)
    @ConfigurationProperties(TWO_DATASOURCE_PREFIX)
    public DataSourceProperties twoDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = TWO_DATASOURCE_BEAN_NAME)
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = TWO_DATASOURCE_CONFIGURATION_PREFIX)
    public DataSource twoDataSource(
            @Qualifier(TWO_DATASOURCE_PROPERTIES_BEAN_NAME) DataSourceProperties twoDataSourceProperties) {
        return twoDataSourceProperties
                .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .build();
    }


    @Bean(name = TWO_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME)
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean twoLocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier(TWO_DATASOURCE_BEAN_NAME) DataSource twoDataSource
            ) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(twoDataSource)
                .packages(TWO_ENTITY_PACKAGES)
                //.packages(TWO_ENTITY_CLASSES)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = TWO_TRANSACTION_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME)
    public PlatformTransactionManager twoPlatformTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier(TWO_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME) LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean twoEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(Objects.requireNonNull(twoEntityManagerFactory.getObject()));
    }
}
```

The problem is columns are not generating as expected (If I have column name as firstName in my entity then it should generate first_name in database but it is generating as firstname) and my jpa properties in application.yml are also not working. hibernate.ddl-auto is not working

Comment: Did you have `@Column(name = "column_name")` on  firstName field ?